# How do derive a new class that supports the Object Inspector and Design Mode?

Tags: c++builder

I have needs to override virtual functions of classes/types available in the `Palette`.

How do I do that and still have it be supported by the design view / .dfm and Object Inspector?  If I try to add change it in the .dfm, it stays it's not a known type.  If I only change in the .h then on each save it says it should be the base class and on startup it prompts that it can't find the base class type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to support design-time is to implement your component's code inside a package, and then install that package into the IDE and have it register the component onto the Palette. Then you can use the component in the Designer in your projects.

There is full documentation on this topic on Embarcadero's website:

[Making Components Available at Design Time](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Making_Components_Available_at_Design_Time)

Also have a look at:

[VCL Component Writer's Guide](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/VCL_Component_Writer%27s_Guide_Index)

[Modifying an existing component](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Modifying_an_existing_component_Index)